# Excel VBA Pivot Table Calculated Field Creation Using Variables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field, vba

I have looked around SO and haven't found an answer to this type of question.  It is probably something trivial that I am doing wrong, but I have tried several different formats of the below with no success.  I have a very long VBA script which uses calculations to determine which fields to include in the pivot.  I then take the variable fields returned and turn them into variables (pivot1, pivot2, etc.).  I can't name the fields specifically in the addition of the calculated field, as I don't know what they will be.  The second segment of code throws off the error "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class".  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Table 1").CalculatedFields.Add "Total", "= pivot1 _
    & " + " & pivot2 & " + " & pivot3 & " + " & pivot4 & " + " & pivot5 & " + " & pivot6 _
    & " + " & pivot7 & " + " & pivot8 & " + " & pivot9 & " + " & pivot10 & " + " & pivot11 _
    & " + "& pivot12", True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Table 1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables _
    ("Pivot Table 1").PivotFields("Total"), "Grand Total", xlSum
```

Comment: are `pivot` variables string type? . Also remove extra `"` after `pivot12"`

Comment: Yes, they are string type.  Sorry, I should have included that.

Comment: see my 2nd sentence. just edited comment

Comment: actually, you have more syntax issues. Try this:     `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Table 1").CalculatedFields.Add "Total", "=" & pivot1 _
        & " + " & pivot2 & " + " & pivot3 & " + " & pivot4 & " + " & pivot5 & " + " & pivot6 _
        & " + " & pivot7 & " + " & pivot8 & " + " & pivot9 & " + " & pivot10 & " + " & pivot11 _
        & " + " & pivot12, True`

Comment: That worked beautifully.  Thank you!